# GCC no longer implements <varargs.h>

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gcc-warning

I have to change this code fragment from varargs.h to stdarg.h, but I do not know exactly how to:

```
#ifndef lint
int ll_log (va_alist)
va_dcl
{
    int event, result;
    LLog   *lp;
    va_list ap;

    va_start (ap);

    lp = va_arg (ap, LLog *);
    event = va_arg (ap, int);

    result = _ll_log (lp, event, ap);

    va_end (ap);

    return result;
}
```

When I try build this, compiler says:

```
error "GCC no longer implements <varargs.h>."
error "Revise your code to use <stdarg.h>."
```

The program, which I need to compile and run, has a few similar fragments and I need to know how to change them. If you can write some example, I'll be content.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<varargs.h>` is a pre-standard C header; use `<stdarg.h>` instead. The differences:

1. The function must take at least one named argument.
2. The function must be prototyped (using the ellipsis terminator).
3. The `va_start` macro works differently: it takes two arguments, the first being the `va_list` to be initialized and the second the name of the last named argument.

Example:

```
int ll_log (LLog *llog, ...) {
    int event, result;
    LLog   *lp;
    va_list ap;

    va_start (ap, llog);

    lp = llog;
    event = va_arg (ap, int);

    result = _ll_log (lp, event, ap);

    va_end (ap);
    return result;
}
```

Regarding `va_start`: gcc ignores the second argument, but not giving the correct one is not portable.

Answer (score 4):

You have to include

```
#include <stdarg.h>
```

va_ Macro syntax stays the same.

Comment: This is correct. I'd also add that you can now use the `int ll_log (...) {` syntax, which wasn't available with `<varargs.h>`

Comment: Wikipedia actually [has a nice description of the change](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h#varargs.h)

Comment: The macro syntax is not the same.  Even ignoring the non-appearance of `va_dcl` in the `<stdarg.h>` system, the `va_start()` macro is different, taking one argument in the old `<varargs.h>` system and two in the new(er) `<stdarg.h>` system.