# in #define directive, how to fix the "expected declaration specifiers before"?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have source code contains cccp.c file. on line 195 there is:

```
#if defined (__STDC__) && defined (HAVE_VPRINTF)
# include <stdarg.h>
# define VA_START(va_list, var) va_start (va_list, var)
# define PRINTF_ALIST(msg) char *msg, ...
# define PRINTF_DCL(msg)
# define PRINTF_PROTO(ARGS, m, n) \
            PROTO (ARGS) __attribute__ ((format (__printf__, m, n)))
#else
# include <varargs.h>
# define VA_START(va_list, var) va_start (va_list)
# define PRINTF_ALIST(msg) msg, va_alist
# define PRINTF_DCL(msg) char *msg; va_dcl  ////====here is the error
# define PRINTF_PROTO(ARGS, m, n) () __attribute__ ((format (__printf__, m, n)))
# define vfprintf(file, msg, args) \
    { \
      char *a0 = va_arg(args, char *); \
      char *a1 = va_arg(args, char *); \
      char *a2 = va_arg(args, char *); \
      char *a3 = va_arg(args, char *); \
      fprintf (file, msg, a0, a1, a2, a3); \
    }
#endif

...

void
warning (PRINTF_ALIST (msg))
     PRINTF_DCL (msg)   ///the use macro part
{
  va_list args;

  VA_START (args, msg);
  vwarning (msg, args);
  va_end (args);
}

static void
fatal (PRINTF_ALIST (msg))
     PRINTF_DCL (msg)
{
  va_list args;

  fprintf (stderr, "%s: ", progname);
  VA_START (args, msg);
  vfprintf (stderr, msg, args);
  va_end (args);
  fprintf (stderr, "\n");
  exit (FATAL_EXIT_CODE);
}
```

and my compiler shows this error for:

```
error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘va_dcl’
195 | # define PRINTF_DCL(msg) char *msg; va_dcl
```

when to define macro apply, it is like:

```
PRINTF_DCL (msg)
```

the source file similar like: [https://cis.temple.edu/~ingargio/cis307/software/mico/cpp/cccp.c](https://cis.temple.edu/%7Eingargio/cis307/software/mico/cpp/cccp.c)
But in that file that code line is 199.

I don't know why there is ';' before va_dcl. And do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The link you have provided uses that macro for K&R style function declarations. But we don't know whether you are doing exactly the same and whether you have done it exactly correctly or not. So you need to provide an MVE.

Comment: @kaylum I add the the code block, it  exactly the same of cccp.c including the name, but do not know why is compile error.

Comment: That's still not an MVE. An MVE is the smallest amount of complete code that anyone can use to reproduce the problem. You have not even provided the complete code that uses the macros (one line is not enough as the surrounding context matters). That's likely where the error is and not in the macro definition itself. Specifically, are you using `PRINTF_DCL` in a function declaration or are you calling it inside a function?

Comment: @kaylum I added the calling part of  PRINTF_DCL, is that OK?

Comment: This is a very old program, and it is set up to be compiled as part of a larger package whose Makefiles provide definitions of macros like `HAVE_VPRINTF`. Can you explain what you're trying to do with it, and why you're not using the build system that it came with?

Comment: @zwol it is a very old code. I check out from https://svn.code.sf.net/p/omniorb/svn/trunk omniorb-svn. This is because, I try to use python3 with omniorb, from pip website https://pypi.org/project/omniorb/#files I find omniorb only support windows version of python3, but I try to use them on ubuntu(linux)

Answer (score 1):

`va_dcl` is an obsolete facility, used to declare variadic functions in language dialects dating to long before standardization. (Reference [1](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-bugs/1998-11/msg00245.html), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24950362/gcc-no-longer-implements-varargs-h))

I suspect that the compiler is going down the wrong path here. Try compiling with `-DHAVE_VPRINTF` on the command line.